# How to checkout a repository outside of the workspace in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repo and where I have created self-hosted runner on windows server 2019.

I want to clone the repo to a different folder than the workspace.

As I linked many things there.

```
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
     path: c:\git\myfolder
```

I tried like above by providing path parameter. But got error as below.

Error: Repository path 'c:\git\myfolder' is not under 'C:\actions-runner\test

I tried the below workflow but still clones to the default folder only.

```
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action@v3
    with:
      owner: myname
      repository: myrepo
      path-to-clone: c:\git\myrepo
```

Also getting this error.

```
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've created a Github action which `v3` branch (still testing) currently allows to perform what you want. If you want to check and give me a feedback, the issue related to it is here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action/issues/3 

Comment: I tried this but getting this error,

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

It seems need to create a separate token, any sample on how to use?

Comment: Sure, I've made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester34.yml) and you can find the workflow run [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/6572504279?check_suite_focus=true). I ended up finding some issue on this `v3` branch (which I'm still testing) and I think this test helped me resolve it. Let me know if it works!

Comment: What should be the entry if I want to clone the same repo where the workflow is running with same branch which the actions triggered?

Comment: The workflow is running in the `${{ github.workspace }}` so you should use this variable. Now, if you want to change the branch, you will need to go inside the repo folder after cloning it (`cd` command) then change the branch using the `git checkout <branch>` command.

Comment: I added the step I tried as you suggested above, but folder not changing.

Comment: Has the repository been cloned successfully using the action?

Answer (score 2):

Cloning outside of your workspace is currently not possible and there's an [open issue in actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/197).

They suggest the workaround to add a run step after the checkout and move the checked out folder:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - run: mv /path/to/my/folder /path/to/my/target
```

Comment: this won't be feasible.
1. Let's say I cloned the repo first, it will move to second folder after clone.
2. next run, it need to download again completely, because repo files are moved to different folder.
3. Old tool, jenkins itself having this option, github also should have

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action/issues/3

```
uses: GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action@v3
  with:
    owner: <owner>
    repository: <repo-name>
    path-to-clone: <path/to/clone>
```

Comment: Hi @Smaurya GuiFalourd already suggested that but having issue as I mentioned in the details above

Comment: Oh, I see now..